# How to specify container options in docker compose file?

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I have deployed multiple containers using a docker-compose.yml file on a raspberry pi.
I would like to specify some options for one of those containers.
How can I do this ?

To be more specific:
I am using the docker image [dastrasmue/rpi-samba](https://github.com/dastrasmue/rpi-samba) and I want to set the options `-v /data:/share/data` and `-u "pi:secret"` and `-s "Pi (private):/share/data:rw:pi"` but I have no clue how I can do this in a composite docker application.

Comment: https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#volume-configuration-reference

Comment: I think you are mixing docker volumes and samba shares that are set with the above `-v` option.  Those are not the same things.

Comment: I have updated questions with some other options I would like to set.

Comment: `-v` on `run` sets volumes. The `volumes` section of the compose file sets the same thing.

Comment: thanks for the answer, but how can I set the other options `-u` and `-s` ?

Comment: Please read the related docs; look up what those options are doing, then search for the same thing in the compose file reference.

Comment: Options `-u` and `-s` are handled by the script `run.sh` (https://github.com/dastrasmue/rpi-samba/blob/master/run.sh) of the docker container.  You are right about the `-v` option but options `-u` and `-s` are specific options for that container.  I also didn't find a corresponding thing in the compose file reference for those 2 options.

Comment: There's a sample `docker run` invocation at line 57 of that script; the options after the image name are command-line arguments to the script itself.

Comment: Yes, that is clear in case you run a single container application, but how do you do that when using a multi container application that is specified through a docker-compose.yml file.

Comment: Thanks, adding the line `command: -s "Public (readonly):/mount:ro:"` to the docker compose yml file did indeed created a public samba share.